# Where has nuget support in Resharper 9 gone?

Tags: resharper, nuget, resharper-9.0

I recently updated Resharper to version 9.0. Now I noticed that adding references by Resharper context menu does no longer update the `packages.config` file, thus breaking the match between referenced DLLs and installed packages.

For older versions of Resharper, this functionality was provided by a [plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-nuget), but the plugin does not seem to support Resharper 9.0. Also, I am unable to find something similar through the Resharper Extension Manager.

**What is the correct way to add Nuget packages to `packages.config` when adding references with Resharper 9.0?**

Comment: I've had resharper 9 installed for a while and hadn't noticed until today that it wasn't updating my packages.config file!

Answer (score 2):

NuGet support was shipped as a bundled plug-in in ReSharper 8. Currently this plugin is still not adopted to ReSharper 9, so you have to wait till it will become compatible, sorry.

But it will become compatible [relatively soon](https://twitter.com/fvilers/status/557823894489681920), hopefully.

Comment: I also found the respective issue on the plugin project page, see https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-nuget/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

Update: According to the creator of the plugin, **this functionality will be shipped with Resharper 9.1**, see [this issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-nuget/issues/23) for the announcement.

That means with Resharper 9.0 we have to keep the `packages.config` in sync with the references manually.